# Best way to prevent an error when calling remove() on a non-existing element

Tags: javascript

This causes an error:

```
document.querySelector('#element-that-does-not-exist').remove()
```

The way I fix it:

```
let el = document.querySelector('#element-that-does-not-exist')
if (el) {
  el.remove()
}
```

My question - is there a more elegant way to prevent an error? One line of code preferably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the safe navigation operator:

```
document.querySelector('#element-that-does-not-exist')?.remove()
```

In this way, if `querySelector` returns `null`, `remove()` won't be called.

If you are not using a transpiler like Babel or Webpack, you may be interested in knowing the compatibility table: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining